# How do i get rid of this Â next to my copyright symbol?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, character-encoding, notepad++

Viewing an html file through Google Chrome version 42.0.2311.90 being edited through Notepad++ version 6.7.9.2 through Citrix Reciever (client software that allows universal access to virtual applications and desktops). I'm putting in text near the end, where a copyright symbol would be, but when I view it in the browser, to the left of the © is this funky Â character. In the encoding drop-down menu in Notepad++, it says the encoding is set to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". Below is all my coding concerning the text:

HTML:

`<body>
    <div id="end">
        <p id="en">© Charity Checker</p>
    </div>
</body>`

(CSS portion is having horrible errors so I wont post it. Sorry.)

Comment: What `Content-type` header do you see when you do `curl -I <url>` or `wget -S <url>` with the URL of the document? (Or if you inspect the headers in devtools.) It seems like your Web server may be sending it with the wrong charset in the Content-type` header (probably sending it with ISO-8859-1).

Comment: ^Different character but same reason.

Comment: sideshowbarker: I actually can't do this because this document is not actually online. the "url" is file:///H:/CC/KMC.html and both of those just lead me to a google search wielding no results.

Comment: FIXED: changed encoding options, Â disappeared